# Using Com+ (VBScript) Function in a SQL Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, vbscript

I usually use this code to Encode a string using a DLL Com+ Component/Object and am wondering how and if something like this can be done inside a SQL function somehow?

I know how to write SQL functions, but not involving objects from the Com+ library, can this be accomplished?

This is how I would write the code in an application:

```
sMyKey = "1234567"
sStr = "Text to be encoded"

Set Crypt = server.CreateObject("aspCrypt.EasyCRYPT")
 Crypt.Algorithm = 162
 Crypt.Mode = cmCTS
 Crypt.Counter( -1 )
 Crypt.initKey( sMyKey )

 sEncodedString = Crypt.EncodeString( sStr , 1 )

Set Crypt = Nothing
```

This returns `sEncodedString` How would I write this code in a SQL function?

Comment: Your current code looks like it's `VBScript`? Why don't you put TSQL in VBScript rather than trying to do VBScript in TSQL? Consider using ADODB to connect to your SQL Server.

Comment: Yes VBScript, because doing it on the SQL Server side would make it much easier to maintain the data and faster.

Comment: Okay, server side VBScript. There's ASP?

Comment: SQL Server side, not asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, a bit of googling reveals there's `sp_OACreate`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189763.aspx